# Threading and SOLID principle

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, solid-principles

I have a the following code setup

```
public interface ILogger
{
  void WriteData(string Data);
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
  public void WriteData(string Data)
  {
     //Write to disk   
  }
}

public interface ILogic
{
  void ProcessData(string Data);
}

public class Logic : ILogic
{
  private ILogger Logger;

  public Logic(ILogger Logger)
  {
    this.Logger = Logger;
  }

  public void ProcessData(string Data)
  {
     //Do stuff
     Logger.WriteData("Data to write");
  }
}

public class MainEntryPointClass
{
     private BlockingCollection<string> DataInCollection;
     private Task DataInTask;
     private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource;

     public Start()
     {
        InitializeDataIn();
     }

        private void InitializeDataIn()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            DataInCollection = new BlockingCollection<DataInContents>();
            DataInTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessDataIn(CancellationTokenSource.Token));
        }

      private void ProcessDataIn(CancellationToken CancelToken)
        {
            while (!CancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                foreach (var item in DataInCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    Logic.ProcessData(item);
                }
            }

        }
}
```

So I create a new Task in my main class and then data is added to the DataInCollection to queue up data as it comes in, we're talking every 30ms or so. This gets processed successfully.

I now want to write data to file on a separate thread just so if there is a disk problem the main logic checking isn't impacted. If there is a disk problem then the logic can continue. I'm just not sure where I do the file writing on the separate thread? Is it in the Main class, the Logic class or the Logger class?

Comment: maybe using a logger-implementation for this question is bad ... someone will come up with the sentence: "why reinvent the wheel? take eg log4net" ... you better point out the real base-question!

Comment: because no 3rd party references allowed and also I cannot determine that NLog writes on another thread. It allows you to call it from various threads but not sure if actually writes on a separate thread. I raised a forum question and on SO but no answers.

Comment: i'm still not getting your base question ... is it a) how do i handle `WriteDataToFile`-calls when operation sometimes throws an exception b) how do i separate the `WriteDataToFile`-call from my current thread, so that i can move on with my execution ...?? and, in the end, "no 3rd party refs are allowed" ... what is the explanation for that? ... reasonable one? hello!?

Comment: the main question is b. regarding 3rd party stuff, who knows, not my decision!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `Logger`'s responsibility to ensure that it doesn't block the caller. It can use many different strategies for that. You don't want to bake those strategies into the class that uses it.

I'd enqueue the message into a `BlockingCollection<T>`, and have a single IO thread write it out to the disk.

I also recommend imitating an existing logging interface, such as [Common.Logging's `ILog`](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/blob/master/src/Common.Logging/Logging/ILog.cs) so you can easily switch to an existing logging framework if your "no third party" requirement gets ever lifted.

Something like:

```
class AsyncLogger:ILogger
{
  public AsyncLogger(ILogger backingLogger)
  {
    new Thread(()=>
      {
        while(true)
        {
          var data=_queue.Take();
          _backingLogger.WriteData(data);
        }
      }
    ).Start();
  }

  public void WriteData(string data)
  {
     _queue.Enqueue(data);
  }
}
```

(I omitted stuff like a termination condition for IO thread, fields, handling of multiple loggers,...)

Comment: So similar to what I have with the BlockingCollection and Task?

Comment: If a queue wasn't used and you just fired up a Task to do the async would there be a problem? An example here https://gist.github.com/2235771

Comment: @Jon That leads to ordering problems. You'd also need to add manual locking to serialize access to the `backingLogger`.

Answer (score 1):

The Logger class is hopefully responsible for logging. So it seems like the right place to log the incoming data to disk.

Comment: Should that be a similar design by using a BlockingCollection and Task?

Comment: @Jon, you can use what you want. Just make your `Logger.WriteData ` function work asynchronous: Store the data in some threadsafe collection and spin of another thread/task.

Comment: @Jan Thanks, next problem integration testing with asynchronous logic :(

Comment: @Jan Wish they would and tell me how to do it :)